# Reverse isekai manga about a demon lord's daughter who is banished to Earth and ends up living in an apartment building

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga is a comedy about a demon lord that banishes his daughter to Earth and she ends up living in an apartment building owned by a bored, rich dude. I remember that one of the tenants is a woman who tries to seduce the landlord to get his riches.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the demon lord's daughter?

Comment: It was mostly black and white

Comment: Is the demon lord's daughter the main character, or just one of many tenants? Do you remember what she does after being banished? Work? Go to school? Laze about? Any idea how old she looked, e.g. child, teenager, adult?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the demon daughter is the main character, she's small and I think she's sent to earth to train or something one of her tasks was to summon a familiar and she ends up summoning a round duck thing, I think she is a shut in and one of many tenants in the apartment,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Strange Creature at Kuroyuri Apartments](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-strange-creature-at-kuroyuri-apartments)*. It is licensed by [Yen Press](https://yenpress.com/9781975327569/the-strange-creature-at-kuroyuri-apartments-vol-1/).

> Meet Meme, the good-for-nothing daughter of the Demon World's mighty summoner clan. **Her dad's kicked her out into the human world to learn some responsibility**, and she needs to find a home! Enter Sentarou Narigane, **wealthy landlord** of Kuroyuri Apartments. Suffering from the worst case of malaise, Sentarou offers Meme a free apartment on one condition: she needs to make him have fun!

The story opens with Meme being a layabout in the demon world, and her father kicks her out. She's unable to find a place to live or anything to eat without money, but finds a flyer advertising a free room with no deposit. She goes there and is told that the landlord is super rich but got bored of it, so he wants his tenants to entertain him.

[image: Cover image]

Her first attempt at entertaining him involves summoning a strange creature, which is shown on the cover page.

Comment: This is the one, thank you

Comment: @Ghostikko You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).